# Firefox is not finishing ajax request when asked to print page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, printing

Here I request print after I insert into a mysql db that the page was printed(I did not find a way to trigger the insert after the page is printed so I put it before), which is inside a $(document).ajaxComplete() block:

```
$("#bPrintIes").off().on("click",function(){
    if(confirm("Confirmati Printarea!")){
        var codCom=$("#codCom").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"php/facturi/iesirePrintare.php",
            data:{ies:"print",codCom:codCom}
        }).done(function(){
            window.print();
        });

    }
});
```

#bPrintIes is a button, in case you needed to know.

- First issue is that it shows a second dialog which asks the user to
  "block future messages".
- Second issue is that prints another blank    page.

The issues are inside Firefox and IE, Chrome does it's job.

I want to show the print dialog and when I press Ok/Accept it should print the page, without the dialog to "block future messages" from the page and without the blank page.

I am ussing JQuery 1.10.2.
Any ideeas/suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? That is prints another blank page? That it gives an additional popup? What should it do?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, hope it is more clear now.